# Is there a way to mark all buffers as "visited"?

Tags: buffers, quit

I recognize that this is a very minor problem, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

I mainly use Neovim, but to keep things simple, I'm going to be referring to and testing with vanilla Vim 9.0.

### The "Problem":

When I am editing multiple buffers (E.g., `vim src/*`) and try to close without individually viewing each and every buffer, Vim helpfully tells me, `E173: 7 more files to edit`.

The problem is that I don't care if there are "more files to edit". I only care about whether there are files with unmodified changes.

EDIT: I know that I can still close Vim by just quitting a second time.

### Potential solutions:

#### `:bn|bn|bn|bn|bn|bn|bn|bn|bn`

This works, but it's obviously not a realistic solution. I don't want to put this in my config or to have to type it out.

#### `:q!`

This works, but discards changes, which I don't want.

#### Stop using globs to open Vim

This is probably the correct answer, but there are benefits to being able to use "*" when opening up multiple files that I would rather not dismiss.

P.S.

If anyone has a use case for why someone would want to know about unvisited buffers, please let me know. To my knowledge, no other editor behaves this way and I would be curious if there are any legitimate use cases I haven't considered.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here are other solutions based on comments:

#### `:wq!`

I dismissed `:q!` because I don't want to discard changes in the current buffer, but `:wq!` solves this issue. The only problem is that it is a longer command than `:q`, but I can write an alias or something.

Comment: Regarding `:q!` discarding changes -- that's only unsaved changes -- `:w`  while editing a file will write those changes to disk, and to my knowledge nothing undoes it if you `:q!`

Comment: @Gus I think you just answered my question. I can just always quit with `:wq!` instead of `:q` like I normally do.

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. Please don't prefix your questions with "it's only a minor problem" etc. It just adds noise and - if anything - reduces your chances of getting good answers.